# Why does this polyline not fit inside the ViewBox in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

What I am trying to achieve is to fit the `Polyline` inside a `Viewbox`. I tried the `Stretch` options, however it does not seem to work with negative values. Can someone guide how to fit the content inside the `ViewBox`?

Following is my sample code:

```xml
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
    <Grid>
        <Polyline Margin="10" Fill="Tan" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Center" Points="0,0 14,0 14,-38" 
                  StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" 
                  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Polyline.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
                    <ScaleTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform.ScaleX>-1</ScaleTransform.ScaleX>
                    </ScaleTransform>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Polyline.RenderTransform>
        </Polyline>
    </Grid>    
</Viewbox>
```

The bounds go beyond the `Viewbox`, hence unable to get it to "fit" the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't set the RenderTransform of an element in a Viewbox.

Instead of a Polyline you may use a Path with a polyline geometry, where you can set the `Transform` property of the `Geometry` object in the Path's `Data`:

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
    <Path Margin="10" Fill="Tan" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M0,0 L14,0 14,-38">
                <PathGeometry.Transform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
                        <ScaleTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform.ScaleX>-1</ScaleTransform.ScaleX>
                        </ScaleTransform>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </PathGeometry.Transform>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Viewbox>
```

Edit: An alternative might be to set the `LayoutTransform` instead of `RenderTransform`. You would also have to set the Polyline's `Stretch` property:

```
<Viewbox>
    <Polyline Margin="10" Fill="Tan" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black"
              Points="0,0 14,0 14,-38" Stretch="Uniform">
        <Polyline.LayoutTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
                <ScaleTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform.ScaleX>-1</ScaleTransform.ScaleX>
                </ScaleTransform>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Polyline.LayoutTransform>
    </Polyline>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Yes, it works in this way, however I wish it to be polyline becauase I am using a custom renderer which joints two points with an arc which gets calculated. Hence the render transform I used, this works well however I am not sure how I am going to integrate this with the existing shape renderer.

Comment: As said, a Viewbox and RenderTransform aren't a good fit. Use either one or the other, not both at the same time. See the edited answer for an alternative.